# Xcode 8.1 freezing on pod install/update

Tags: xcode, freeze, xcode8

Xcode 8.1 freezing every time i run pod install/update, that i have to force quit xcode and open it again. This also happens when i try to merge 2 branches with source control and with terminal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found solution so if anyone has problem with this just move your project outside of icloud. My project was in documents and it was sync to icloud, so when i unsync it it worked perfect.

Note: when you unsync from icloud all you data from documents will be deleted.